# 3d support on AMD Radeon HD 7800M series video card with 3 displays (Dell M6700)

Tags: 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors, radeon

On my Dell M6700 laptop with an AMD Radeon HD 7870M video card I am unable to get 3d support with 3 displays on Ubuntu 12.04.02 (LTS)

With the open source Radeon Driver I can get 3 displays working but no unity 3d support.

With the Proprietary drivers, event the latest 13.4 directly from AMD, I can get 2 displays working, but if I add a third, I get various CRTC errors.

going to xrandr, these errors seem to be associated with enabling crtc 2.

IE:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:6825]

$ xrandr --verbose --fb 6016x1152 --output LVDS --auto --output DFP5 --auto --right-of LVDS --output DFP9 --auto --right-of DFP5

screen 0: 6016x1152 1592x305 mm  95.94dpi
crtc 0:    2048x1152   59.9 +1920+0 "DFP5"
crtc 1:    2048x1152   59.9 +3968+0 "DFP9"
crtc 2:    1920x1080   60.0 +0+0 "LVDS"
xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
crtc 3: disable
crtc 4: disable
crtc 5: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
crtc 3: revert
crtc 4: revert
crtc 5: revert

$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7800M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12217 Compatibility Profile Context FireGL 12.104
```

Everything I read says it should be possible with this version of the catalyst drivers (currently 13.4) and linux.  And the card supports Eyefinity. (6 displays)

I've tried various outputs with display-port and not, and still no luck.

**Does anyone know if a newer version of the radeon driver supports 3d on this card?
Or if there is some way to enable crtc 2 in the fglrx driver for without getting the configuration error?**

When I use amdcccle to configure 3 or more monitors it ends up giving a generic not enough memory or unable to enable display error.  I think this is directly related to the `xrandr:  Configure crtc 2 failed`.

Depending on the configuration I get many different CRTC errors on bootup.  147,148,149 seem the most common.

current xrandr -q shows the following

```
$ xrandr-q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4096 x 1152, maximum 6016 x 2048
LVDS connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   ...
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP5 connected 2048x1152+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   2048x1152      59.9*+
   ...
DFP6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP9 connected 2048x1152+2048+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   2048x1152      59.9*+
   ...
DFP10 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP11 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP12 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This basically confirms my virtual screen size is large enough, and the displays are available.

Answer (score 2):

3D support for the Radeon HD 7000 series in the radeon driver is finally available when combining the Linux 3.9 kernel, Mesa 9.2 and LLVM 3.3.

You have two options:

1. Wait for the release of Ubuntu 13.10 "Saucy Salamander" on 17th October 2013.  It currently has the 3.10 kernel and might even update to the 3.11 kernel.  They are also planning to pull Mesa 9.2 (currently scheduled for release on 22nd August 2013) into Ubuntu 13.10 - you can monitor that at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa
2. Install a 3.9 or 3.10 kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
   Instructions on how to install and uninstall it are available at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds
   Note that this is more likely to be successful on Ubuntu 13.04 than on earlier Ubuntu versions.  Then install the xorg-edgers PPA to get Mesa 9.2-devel.

P.S.: The xorg-edgers PPA is available at at https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa